# Composer dependency package altering

Tags: composer-php

How can I modify an external package's composer.json file by **only** modifying my own project's composer.json file?

This is for testing purposes only. I need to test if a package is compatible with a very new version of another package.

**My project composer.json:**

```
{
    "require": {
        "foo/framework": "1.2.0",
        "bar/extension": "1.1.0"
    }
}
```

**External package (`bar/extension`) composer.json:**

```
{
    "require": {
        "foo/framework": "1.2.0"
    }
}
```

So this obviously works. But let's say I want to have the new version of `foo/framework`, which is `1.3.0`. This won't work because `bar/extension` depends on the older version.

Using only my project's composer.json, how can I change the requirement for the `bar/extension` package?

Comment: Submit a pull request to the author of foo/framework, if he's applying [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) 1.2 to 1.3 is a minor backwards compatible change and should just work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may override `composer.json` of dependency using repository with [`package`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) type. In your `composer.json` add something like this (URLs should to be adjusted):

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "bar/extension",
            "version": "1.1.0",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/bar/extension/archive/1.1.0.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
            "require": {
                 "foo/framework": "1.2.0 || 1.3.0"
            }
            // rest of necessary settings from original bar/extension composer.json 
        }
    }
],
```

Note that `package` type is very inflexible and creates many problems - I would not recommend using this for anything else than testing. In practice it may be better idea to just fork the package and use [`vcs`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) repository to use it in your project - you will be able to make necessary adjustments in package and propose as pull request to upstream (or just use fork permanently).

Comment: Do I have to specify the "dist"?

Comment: Either `dist` or `source`.

Comment: Having to define the source doesn't really work that well for me because it is coming from a private satis repo. Anyway, I didn't mention that and this is probably the closest I can get to it also, so for that reason I'm awarding you the answer and bounty here.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea, if `bar/extension` depends on older versions, you should not use newer versions of `foo/framework`, because it could be not compatible with a newer version and will cause bugs in your application.

But if `bar/extension` on the range of version and you want to use the newest from this range, you could specify this with [conflict](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#conflict) directive.

Or even you can try the [replace](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace) directive.